# How does jQuery FadeIn know the used display mode?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

Simple question: How does jQuery know what display mode an element should use when using fadeIn?

What I mean, is that it appears to use the proper display mode for any element that I fadeIn, even when I set `display:none` **initially** in my CSS - images are using inline, divs are using block, etc.

I looked into the jQuery source code on GitHub, but I couldnt locate what I was looking for.

Reason I ask is because I am making a little plugin myself, using fade (but with Animate, since there is more than 1 property that needs animation).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It uses [`$.data`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) to store it:

```
console.log($._data( elem, "olddisplay" ));
```

The underscore means that it can access data that is not normally available through `$.data` or `$.fn.data`. Basically this is for internal use only and you should not touch it.

If the element is set to `display:none` through CSS, and you fade it in, jQuery still knows to make it `inline` etc. In this case, it uses the function

```
// Try to determine the default display value of an element
function css_defaultDisplay( nodeName ) {
```

Which would give `"inline"` for a `nodeName === "span"`

Comment: When is this data being assigned?

Comment: @Jeff when you call `.hide()`

Comment: I usually set display:none on all elements that I plan to fade in later, in CSS, and it still appears to work?

Comment: @Jeff Did you have a further question in there?

Comment: No, this question was raised due to the fact that it somehow magically knows the correct display mode, no matter if I set display:none in the CSS initially

Comment: @Jeff I noticed you edited the question, here's the github link https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css.js#L447

Comment: Great! Can I use this in my own code without having to declare it manually?

Comment: @Jeff you mean the `css_defaultDisplay` function? No, it's not available outside jQuery definition code. You'd have to write it and a bunch of other internal dependencies manually or modify jQuery code to expose it

Comment: @Jeff yep you can see it "break" in exceptionally stupid situations like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4wndX/ :D jQuery will make it inline even though it shouldn't :P

Comment: Yeah, thats sucks, thats why I will include a toDisplay property in my plugins settings ;)